# javascript-comparing two strings in an array to see if they are equal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare  the word hello and hey both of which are in an array if they are equal and my code is returning true and yet they are not. how can i modify my code to make it return false when comparing the two words.

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var sorted =[];
  for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++)  {
    sorted.push(arr[i].toLowerCase());
  }


  for (var j =0; j<sorted.length;j++)  {
    for(var k=0; k<sorted.length; k++)  {
      if(sorted[j]  == sorted[k])  {
        return true;
      } else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: Your code is confusing. It seems to assume that there are only ever two elements in the array. Is that correct? Then why don't you just use `arr[0].toLowerCase() === arr[1].toLowerCase()`?

Comment: compared to this O(n²) way of searching for a single duplicate, this is very short and faster: `new Set(arr).size !== arr.length` but what the code does (after correcting the k-loop as suggested in an answer) and what the text says are different things

Comment: You have got two string and you need function?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the second loop to start from j+1, because you are actually comparing 0 with 0 positions.

```
for(var k=j+1; k<sorted.length; k++)  {
```

Comment: If he or she have got two string in one array.You can only use array[0]==array[1]?this question so good funny:)

Answer (score 0):

The code sample given the argument provided to 'mutation' has 2 items. My solution also presumes that arr is an Array containing 2 items.

```
function mutation(arr) {
  if(arr[0] !== arr[1]) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```